# ¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de una cuenta de Paypal en cuanto hace un pago?

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

Recién vi una tienda en línea, donde sin hacer un registro previo agregué un producto al carrito y pagué con paypal. Al cerrarse la ventana de Paypal donde se muestra tu cuenta, el total a pagar y se confirma el pago; apareció en la tienda en línea información que yo tengo en mi cuenta de Paypal. Como mi nombre y dirección. Esta información llenó los campos de un formulario.

Actualmente yo estoy haciendo algo similar en Angular y estoy utilizando [ngx-paypal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-paypal) para la conexión y procesar los pagos. Este componente tiene un método llamado `onPaymentComplete` el cual se ejecuta al procesar la compra correctamente.

```
onPaymentComplete: (data, actions) => {}
```

La data que me regresa el método es algo como esto:

```
{
  intent: "sale"
  orderID: "XXX-YYY"
  payerID: "XXX-payer"
  paymentID: "XXX-payment"
  paymentToken: "XXX-YYY"
  returnUrl: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/?paymentId=XXX-payment&token=XXX-YYY&PayerID=XXX-payer"
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Alguno de estos datos podría servirme para consultar la información del usuario y que me regrese el nombre o dirección?

Comment: Puedes encontrar cómo obtener datos del usuario de pago de PayPal en la siguiente documentación https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_get_payment_details/#response . Te recomendaría que estás llamadas se hagan desde el back evitando que se obtenga está información con un sniffer.